# Probability of a vector being in a predefined interval in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, contest-math, physics

Suppose we have a two-dimensional vector of constant length that is equally likely to point in any direction specified by $\theta$, measured from the $x$-axis. Compute the probability that the $x$-component of $v_{x}$ lies between $v_{x}$ and $v_{x} + \mathop{dx}$.

Comment: Is $dx$ finite or infinitesimal?

Comment: $dx$ is a finite number.

Comment: Is $|\vec v|=v$ a constant? Or can it vary as well? If it's a constant, do you have that $-v\le v_X\le v_X+dx\le v$?

Comment: It is a constant. I do not know if $v_{x} \leq v_{x} + \mathop{dx}$, but I think that this can be fixed by just taking the absolute value?

Comment: I've added more details in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector is given by $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$, where $r$ is fixed and $\theta$ is chosen uniformly at random.  The $x$-component is in the interval $[x_0,x_1]$ (where $-r\le x_0 \le x_1 \le r$) if
$$r\cos\theta\in[x_0, x_1] \iff \cos\theta\in\left[\frac{x_0}{r},\frac{x_1}{r}\right].$$
There will be two equal-sized intervals of $\theta$ satisfying this, one above the $x$-axis and one below: $\theta\in[\cos^{-1}(x_0/r), \cos^{-1}(x_1/r)]$ and its reflection.  So the probability that the $x$-component is between $x_0$ and $x_1$ is
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x_1}{r}\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x_0}{r}\right)\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not a double integral.  However the probability has to be split into two parts.  Specifically $(v=|\overrightarrow{v}|)$, let $p=P(v_x\le u)=P(vcos\theta \le u)=P(vcos\theta \le u,0\le \theta\le \pi)+P(vcos\theta \le u,\pi\le \theta\le 2\pi)$.  Let $w=\frac{u}{v}$  Then $p=(\theta\ge arccos(w),0\le \theta\le \pi)+P(\theta\le arccos(w),\pi\le \theta \le 2\pi)=\frac{|\pi-arccos(w)|}{\pi}$

Note that the arccos is double valued over the interval $0,2\pi$, but $\pi-arccos(w)$ is the same for both values.

Comment: why does it need to be split ?

Comment: $v_x$ is not a monotone function of $\theta$.  For $0\le \theta \le \pi$, $v_x$ goes from $1$ to $-1$ and for $\pi \le \theta \le 2\pi$, $v_x$ goes from $-1$ to $1$.  As a result the distribution function for $v_x$ starts at $\theta =\pi$ and increases as $|\theta -\pi|$ increases in both directions.  The contribution to CDF is calculated by adding the contributions from each piece.

Answer (score 0):

Probabilities are defined with respect to distributions, that is, you need to provide a way to go from a collection of possibilities (called an event) to a number between $0$ and $1$. In this context, a distribution over $\mathbb{R}^2$, you would typically provide a function of two variables whose double integral was $1$, and then the probability of an arbitrary event is the integral of that function over that region.

But there's no magical choice for the function, for the distribution, in this case. One could make an argument for a bivariate normal, but there's no definitive reason to choose that.

Comment: $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over $0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: but that doesn't tell you about the magnitude of the vector.

Comment: the answer will be in terms of $|v|$

Comment: You'll be able to write it down as an integral, with the distribution of lengths featuring in the integral, but that's as close as you'll get.

Comment: can't it just be computed as a ratio of the arc length area formed by $v_{x}$ to $v_{x} + \mathop{dx}$ to the arclength of the entire circle?

Comment: $|v|$ is also constant length, if it helps.

Comment: If $v$ has a fixed length, then yes, you can just do an arclength calculation, but that wasn't clear from your initial post